# Binding a grid to a drop down list

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a grid that I want to show depending on the result of the drop down list. I can't seem to be able to send the values to the select("controller", "action", data) method. How can I do that? I can't get my javascript to handle it.

This is the drop down list

```
                    <select id="workoutType" onchange="changed(value)">
                    @{ foreach (var type in Model.WorkoutTypes)
                      { 
                        <option value="@type"> @type </option>
                      }
                    }
                    </select>
```

and here is the grid

```
                        @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Approvers)
                            .Name("Orders")
                            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
                                //Ajax binding
                                  .Ajax()
                                //The action method which will return JSON
                                      .Select("__AjaxBinding", "AssetResearch", new { workoutType = ViewData["dropDownValue"] })
                            )
                            .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(o => o.InvestorName).Width(125);
                                    columns.Bound(o => o.ApproverType).Title("Type").Width(100);
                                    columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Title("E-mail Address");
                                })
                            .ClientEvents(events => events
                                .OnDataBinding("onDataBinding")
                                )
                            .Pageable()
                            .Sortable()
                    )
```

I tried using Viewbag and sadly I can't seem to pull it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the right way to achieve it because the RouteValue cannot be set on the server (when you are rendering the Grid)

One way to achieve it is to use the change event of the DropDOwnList which Phonixblade9 mentioned to make the Grid perform request and fetch its data from the server. This could be achieved through the **ajaxRequest** method of the Grid.

Here is what I mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#workoutType').change(function(){

        var data = $(this).value;

        var gridClientObject = $('#Orders').data().tGrid;
        gridClientObject.ajaxRequest({workoutType :data});// do not forget to name the parameter in the action again method again 'workoutType'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#workoutType').change(function(){
    //bind your data here
    var data = $(this).value;
    // pass into your C# stuff here
    });
});
```

Would something like this work?